# Converting JSP scriptlet to Adobe Sightly/HTL?

Tags: jsp, aem

I've the following scriptlet in JSP adobe Cq5 and now migrating to Adobe Sightly/HTL.
Have the following code, which will open a new window upon clicking on anchor link, same functionality has to be written in sightly. Can you pls help me here?

---

```
     <% if(!properties.get("buttonlabel","").equals("")){
            String targetUrl ="#";
             targetUrl = properties.get("buttonurl","#");
                    if(targetUrl.startsWith("/content")){
                        targetUrl = targetUrl+".html";
                    }
        String target = "_self";

        if(currentNode.hasProperty("openWindow")){
                    target = "_blank";
                }



    %>
    <!--
    <div class="fcdetails-button-holder">
                            <a href='<%=targetUrl%>' target ='<%=target%>' name='<%=properties.get("buttonlabel","Title")%> button' id="wp-ctoa_button" class="button" role="button"><%=properties.get("buttonlabel","Title")%></a>
                        </div>
    -->

        <div class="fcdetails-button-holder">
        <button type="button" id="wp-ctoa_button" class="button" onclick="redirect()"><%=properties.get("buttonlabel","Title")%></button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function redirect()
            {
                var url = "<%=targetUrl%>";
                window.open(url,"<%=target%>");
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have [this](http://aemtuts.com/aem-sightly-quick-reference/) cheat sheet side by side, will make conversion to sightly a lot easier.

Comment: The linked page is no longer available but is archived here: http://web.archive.org/web/20190520073123/http://aemtuts.com/aem-sightly-quick-reference/

Answer (score 0):

The cool thing about sightly is focusing on improving the "template-iness" of components - and the separation of concerns of logic from representation.  However, JSPs can do all of that also - just that the examples inside AEM show the poorest examples of how to code all that.

Reworking the JSP example:

```
<c:if test="${not empty properties.buttonLabel}">
  <div class="fcdetails-button-holder">
    <button type="button" id="wp-ctoa_button" onclick="redirect()">
      ${empty properties.buttonLabel ? 'Title' : properties.buttonLabel}
    </button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
      var url = '${properties.buttonUrl}' || '#';
      if (url.match(/^\/content\//) url += '.html';
      window.open(url, "${empty properties.openWindow ? '_self' : '_blank'}");
    }
  </script>
</c:if>
```

Now the JSP doesn't look much more complicated than the sightly example.

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic into either Java or server-side JavaScript in order to leave your Sightly template clean and logicless. Here we use the `data-sly-use` block to tie the template with the Java bean and save it to a `button` object to be reused throughout the template. The only other thing that you need to handle is the context within the script tag in order to identify the type of XSS protection Sightly should apply.

```
<sly data-sly-use.button="com.company.project.components.Button" data-sly-test="${button.label}">
    <div class="fcdetails-button-holder">
        <button type="button" id="wp-ctoa_button" class="button" onclick="redirect()" data-sly-text="${button.label}"></button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function redirect()
        {
            var url = "${button.targetUrl @ context='scriptString'}";
            window.open(url, "${button.target @ context='scriptString'}");
        }
    </script>
</sly>
```

Here's an example of a Java bean extending the WCMUsePojo class. You can also look into Sling Models.

```
public class Button extends WCMUsePojo {

    private String label;
    private String target;
    private String targetUrl;

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        ValueMap properties = getProperties();

        label = properties.get("buttonlabel", String.class);
        target =  properties.get("openWindow", false) ? "_blank" : "_self";
        targetUrl = properties.get("buttonurl", "#");

        if (targetUrl.startsWith("/content")) {
            targetUrl += ".html";
        }
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getTargetUrl() {
        return targetUrl;
    }

    public String getTarget() {
        return target;
    }
}
```